# Can 2-4x4x8 wood posts be stacked?

Tags: wood, outdoor, post, brackets

Trying to get a basketball goal set up. Can’t find anywhere that sells metal posts for this. There are however wood posts. We got 2-4x4x8 for a total of 16’. 4’ of which will be cemented in ground. The remaining 12’ will be for adjusting the basketball backboard and bracket as needed. The biggest problem is finding a secure way to attach the 2 posts for the intended use. No one will be dunking on it. Needing it to handle winds and storms. What kind of brackets to use for attaching? Other methods?

Comment: "No one will be dunking on it." The likelihood of this being accurate is close to 0%.

Comment: Where are you that you can not buy steel pipe ?

Comment: There is always one who says 'hold my beer, watch this'.

Comment: You're trying to attach two 8 foot 4x4 posts end-to-end to make a single 16 footer? That sounds dubious...

Comment: Real answer: you haven't looked hard enough to find a supplier.

Comment: Two ways to go about this: Buy a generic steel pipe/post to use, or they sell specific hardware for mounting backboards at sporting goods stores.

Answer (score 2):

Four pieces of 1x4 glued and screwed.

Four pieces of angle iron screwed on the corners. inch and a half or bigger(better)

Four pieces of flat steel screwed on the sides.

Would recommend two foot minimum, but four feet would be nice for the 1x4 wood and steel braces.

Could also cut and notched both pieces at a shallow angle and use glue and screws, but it reduces usable height/length by length of notch. This is probably the nicest looking, but might want longer 4x4s, 10 will work but 12s be a much stronger joint, four foot angle cut on each one.

Comment: You might want to recommend a minimum length for the bandage holding this together. I could see someone making a 6" long patch and expecting that to hold up.

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan  have added the length in.